# Is it possible to add boolean conditions into a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to implement a Decision tree which from my understanding , a Decision Tree is a Binary Tree with boolean conditions , feel free to correct me if i am wrong. I am trying to implement an Add() function with a parameter of a template  where i want to add a boolean conditions. I am using this link : http://csharpexamples.com/c-binary-search-tree-implementation/ for help.I was trying to compare a boolean value with an int value knowing it won't work so i switched to using a template  . This is my first time trying to implement a Binary Search Tree.

Here is the code for my node class:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    
    public class BST_NodeClass<E> 
    {
       public BST_NodeClass<E> LeftNode { get; set; }
       public BST_NodeClass<E> RightNode { get; set; }
       public BST_NodeClass<E> Data { get; set; }
    };
```

Here is the code for my Binary Search Tree :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BST<E> where E : System.IComparable<E>
{
    public BST_NodeClass<E> Root { get; set; }

    public bool Add (E condition) 
    {
        BST_NodeClass<E> before = null, after = this.Root;
        while (after!= null)
        {
            before = after;
            if(condition < after.Data)//Is new node in the left tree?
            {
                after = after.LeftNode;
                
            }
            else if (condition > after.Data)//Is the new node in the right tree?
            {
                after = after.RightNode;
            }
            else
            {
                //Exist same value
                return false;
            }
            BST_NodeClass<E> newNode = new BST_NodeClass<E>();
            newNode.Data = condition;
            if (this.Root == null)//Tree is empty
                this.Root = newNode;
            else
            {
                if (condition < before.Data)
                    before.LeftNode = newNode;
                else
                    before.RightNode = newNode;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
        
};
```

Comment: Sounds like your condition should rather be e.g. a `Func<E, E, bool>` so something that takes two `E`, compares them somehow and then returns a boolean value whether the condition is fulfilled or or not ... but I don't really understand what your question is. So far I only see statements ...

Comment: Ok so i am trying to make a Decision Tree for my AI . I want to add conditions like for example the Root Node will be "Is the Base being attacked ? "( a boolean variable or a function) , if false  , go to the right node , if true , then go to the left node . Does it make sense ? I am bad at explaining ,my apologies.

Comment: hmm i think if i follow this link: https://code.4noobz.net/decision-tree-simple-example/ it will help me understand more , thank you for your responce !

Comment: Ah I see ^^ then still you would pass in a `Func<bool>`, a method that returns a bool so you can check it's value later on

Comment: I can't seem to understand what you mean by that , i just checked and they are BST_NodeClass<E>.

Comment: They are my bad sorry ^^

Comment: I think the issue is that you are trying to start from a sorted values tree ... for your decision tree I don't think you actually want to use an `IComparable` at all you would rather clearly define where and how exactly nodes are chained together. Question is: is your tree strictly linear? or might two different decision paths end up in the same node? In such case it would become quite complex since you will need to ensure there are no circular paths etc

Comment: What i am doing is a Clash Royale Type of game in Unity. What the Decision Tree will do is either Attack or Defend. Defend when the player's AI  has entered the Collision Box i've setted up around the base. There are two paths which both have Collision Boxes. It will Attack when one of the paths is empty , if the Player's AI is pushing the one of those paths ( which sounds like Defending i will think about it more later but for now i want it to stay on Attack). Those are the decisions i've thought of. To answer your question there are two paths (Attack and Defend) . I hope i've answered it.

Comment: Currently  i am following the link: code.4noobz.net/decision-tree-simple-example in the previous comment. For now it makes more sense but it does not follow the binary search tree example.